Embeddings for Vision Transformers
In Natural Language, we know that the embeddings are trained vector representations of words. How does this translate to the embeddings of image patches in vision transformers? How are the embeddings curated?
Also, in language the positional embeddings are computed with the following formula:enter image description here
Are the positional embeddings a learnable entity in case of vision? How's this better than the fixed embeddings in case of the natural language?
I tried reading the ViT paper but it wasn't really clear on these topics
